# WCF - Pass cookie to netHttpBinding (WebSocket) communication

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, cookies

I need to send some cookies from client to server while initializing netHttpBinding (WebSocket) communication.

In case of HTTP-based communication I was achieving the same goal by implementing `IClientMessageInspector` and adding to `Message` properties `HttpRequestMessageProperty` in `BeforeSendRequest` method:

```
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        var properties = request.Properties;
        var propertyName = HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name;
        var httpProperty = properties.ContainsKey(propertyName)
            ? (HttpRequestMessageProperty)properties[propertyName]
            : new HttpRequestMessageProperty();

        httpProperty.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = cookie.ToString();

        properties[propertyName] = httpProperty;

        return null;
    }
```

But I have no ideas of how to achieve the same when I use WebSockets.